# How to either upload or send a txt file after it has been stored to a sd card

Tags: android, file, send, text-files

I am currently working on my first android app for my comp prog class. The app records contacts onto a txt file and stores it on the SD card. I am able to retrieve the file manually, but I now want **the app to send the txt file back to me automatically after it has been created.** Please, what is the easiest way to do this. I use eclipse. It doesn't matter how the txt file gets to me, it just needs to...that is the point of the lesson. This works fine and all permissions and stuff are in order. **I need to know what to put to send and where. Any additional permissions?** I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance. Kevin

```
 package com.lightcone.readcontacts;

       import java.io.File;
       import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
       import java.io.FileOutputStream;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.PrintWriter;

       import android.app.Activity;
       import android.content.ContentResolver;
       import android.database.Cursor;
       import android.net.Uri;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.os.Environment;
       import android.provider.ContactsContract;
       import android.util.Log;
       import android.widget.TextView;
       import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal;

public class ReadContacts extends Activity {


      private static final Uri URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
      private static final Uri PURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
      private static final Uri EURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
      private static final Uri AURI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_URI;
      private static final String ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
      private static final String DNAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
      private static final String HPN = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;
      private static final String LOOKY = ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY;
      private static final String CID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
      private static final String EID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
      private static final String AID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTACT_ID;
      private static final String PNUM = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
      private static final String PHONETYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE;
      private static final String EMAIL = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;
      private static final String EMAILTYPE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE;
      private static final String STREET = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET;
      private static final String CITY = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY;
      private static final String STATE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION;
      private static final String POSTCODE = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE;
      private static final String COUNTRY = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY;

      private String id;
      private String lookupKey;
      private String name;
      private String street;
      private String city;
      private String state;
      private String postcode;
      private String country;
      private String ph[];
      private String phType[];
      private String em[];
      private String emType[];
      private File root;
      private int emcounter;
      private int phcounter;
      private int addcounter;
      private TextView tv;


      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

         em = new String[5];
         emType = new String[5];
         ph = new String[5];
         phType = new String[5];

         checkExternalMedia();

         File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/download");
         dir.mkdirs();
         File file = new File(dir, "phoneData.txt");
         tv.append("Wrote " +file+"\nfor following contacts:\n");

         try{
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);


            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cu = cr.query(URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (cu.getCount() > 0) {    

               while (cu.moveToNext()) {    

                  street = "";
                  city = "";
                  state = "";
                  postcode = "";
                  country = "";

                  id = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(ID));
                  name = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(DNAME));          
                  lookupKey = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(LOOKY));               
                  tv.append("\n"+id+" "+name); 


                  phcounter = 0;
                  if (Integer.parseInt(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex(HPN))) > 0) {             
                     Cursor pCur = cr.query(PURI,  null, CID + " = ?",  new String[]{id}, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        ph[phcounter] = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(PNUM));
                        phType[phcounter]  = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(PHONETYPE)); 
                        phcounter ++;
                     } 
                     pCur.close();
                  }


                  emcounter = 0;
                  Cursor emailCur = cr.query(EURI, null, EID + " = ?",  new String[]{id}, null); 
                  while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
                     em[emcounter] =  emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(EMAIL));
                     emType[emcounter] =  emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(EMAILTYPE));
                     emcounter ++;
                  } 
                  emailCur.close();


                  addcounter = 0;
                  Cursor addCur = cr.query(AURI, null, AID + " = ?",  new String[]{id}, null); 
                  while (addCur.moveToNext()) { 
                     street = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(STREET));
                     city = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(CITY));
                     state = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(STATE));
                     postcode = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(POSTCODE));
                     country = addCur.getString(addCur.getColumnIndex(COUNTRY));
                     addcounter ++;
                  } 
                  addCur.close();

                  pw.println(name+" ID="+id+" LOOKUP_KEY="+lookupKey);
                  for(int i=0; i<phcounter; i++){
                     pw.println("   phone="+ ph[i]+" type="+phType[i] + " ("
                        + getPhoneType(phType[i]) + ") ");
                  }
                  for(int i=0; i<emcounter; i++){
                     pw.println("   email="+ em[i]+" type="+emType[i] + " ("
                        + getEmailType(emType[i]) + ") ");
                  }
                  if(addcounter > 0){
                     if(street != null) pw.println("   street="+street);
                     if(city != null) pw.println("   city="+city);
                     if(state != null) pw.println("   state/region="+state);
                     if(postcode != null) pw.println("   postcode="+postcode);
                     if(country != null) pw.println("   country="+country);
                  }
               }
            }       
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            f.close();       
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("MEDIA", "*************** File not found. Did you" +
               " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the manifest file? ");
         } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }  
      }



      private void checkExternalMedia () {
         boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
         boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
         String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

         if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
         } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
            mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
         } else {
            mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
         }

         root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
         tv.append( "External storage: Exists="+mExternalStorageAvailable+", Writable="
                  +mExternalStorageWriteable+" Root="+root+"\n");
      }



      private String getPhoneType(String index){
         if(index.trim().equals( "1")){
            return "home";
         } else if (index.trim().equals("2")){
            return "mobile";
         } else if (index.trim().equals("3")){
            return "work";
         } else if (index.trim().equals("7")){
            return "other";
         } else {
            return "?";
         }
      }  


      private String getEmailType(String index){
         if(index.trim().equals( "1")){
            return "home";
         } else if (index.trim().equals("2")){
            return "work";
         } else if (index.trim().equals("3")){
            return "other";
         } else if (index.trim().equals("4")){
            return "mobile";
         } else {
            return "?";
         }
      }
   }
```